# Singleton vs Static Class for File Writing and a Mock-Data Base

Tags: java, database, singleton, static-classes

I do recognize that this question has been asked many times before, but I can't get the answer I want out of it. And that question is, "Should I use a singleton or a class with all static members and methods?"

I only ever need one instance for what I am trying to achieve and both ways can work equally well. So designwise, is there a better way to do it? Or should I use either at all?

### First Case:

I am trying to write a "database" class for my program. This "database" uses other objects to store and organize the data. However the database itself sorts and searches the data. And given that it is a database, I only want one instance of it. I don't want to have to access multiple places for data. The database itself handles that.

Note- I already wrote it as enum `Data.BASE`. It uses method `handle(String)` to take a string command and manipulate the data within it by calling other methods. Should I have wrapped `Data.BASE` in a "static class" and used that to talk to `Data.BASE`? (I commuicate directly with `Data.BASE`)

### Second Case:

I have am planning on making a class that is meant to load and save settings from my program called `SettingsManager`. It would *use*, not implement `Savable` interface to manipulate objects with savable settings. `SettingsManager` would be called when the program is begun and ends. However, it can only manipulate objects that are added to it (`SettingsManager.add(Savable)`). Just like the first case, I don't need multiple instances of it. I only want one instance keeping track of writing and saving preferences.

Is there a better way of going about this that I can't think of?

I do recognize that this is not a specific coding question. However, I feel that these are important design and stylistic questions that I will certainly need to reference in the future for other programs.

Comment: I will be going out for lunch. So I apologize if I don't respond right away to any answers/comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first case, if it is just one instance at any given time in your JVM then make it final static; this is faster.

For the second case, if `SettingsManager` is manipulating data in the database, then you can do the dependency injection and let the framework decide when to initiate and destroy it.

The information you provided is not much so I cannot tell you exactly what is better. For example, if we knew you are using Java EE or Java SE or if you are using any framework (like Spring - SpringMVC) that would help us to give you better advice.

Comment: Ok, the key point is you just want one single instance. And you don't like your code to be instantiated twice by mistake anywhere else in your project. So my suggestion is to make that class singleton. 
This link might help you. You may not happen to use DI for your project but it is good to implement something similar by your own (in terms of design perspective): 

http://blog.rocketscience.io/dependency-injection-with-cdi-in-java-se/

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll look at that link later. The computer network I'm on is blocking the site...

Answer (score 2):

I would use dependency injection.
If you want only one database connector object, create it once and pass it to the components which need it.
Just because you only want one instance doesn't mean you have to use a singleton pattern/anti-pattern.

Comment: Well, there is not much to pass it to. My GUI directly accesses the database by taking a user command and passing the command to the database. The database is responsible for holding everything together. I could go deep into my hierarchy but I dont think I have to.

Comment: Also, dependency injection is a new concept to me. I will have to look around.